# Inject templatized Set using Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a member in my class:

```
Class Abc
{
...
    @Autowired
    Set<TestClass> testClasses;
...
}
```

How can I inject it using Spring?

The xml I am using is:

```
<bean id="testClasses" class="java.util.HashSet"/>
```

I am injecting an empty bean because I want it to be an empty set of TestClass types.

But it's giving me the following error:

> No matching bean of type [TestClass] found for dependency [collection
>   of TestClass].

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Can you give your complete spring configuration xml?

Comment: This error is now resolved, I added @Component to TestClass class and added one default constructor. Now when I run it, it's working fine. But the testClasses.size() gives "1" by default. It's adding one default object TestClass. I do not want that. I want to inject an empty set only. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Resource(name="testClasses")
Set<TestClass> testClasses;
```

or

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("testClasses")
Set<TestClass> testClasses;
```

Adding qualifier solves the problem as there might be multiple `Set<TestClass>` types available.

Answer (score 0):

Your bean "testClasses" defined in the xml is not parameterized instead of the autowired values (Set testClasses). So you have to do this:

```
<util:set id="testClasses" value-type="...TestClass" />
```